# Can't start debugger on RubyMine 8.0.3 and Ruby 2.2.4

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase_internals (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta6/lib/debase.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How to fix the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use byebug instead of debugger when you are using ruby version above 1.9.3 .